# How to send Share-point Document using mail attachment from Node Mailer

Tags: node.js, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, nodemailer

I am using `Node Mailer` to send email from node application. Now this mail contains attachment which is a share point link and looks something like below -

```
{   // use URL as an attachment
        filename: 'license.txt',
        path: 'https://raw.github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/master/LICENSE'
}
```

The problem is when I send this mail it gives me `403 forbidden error` which I understand is due to the share point link needs authentication. My question is how do I pass the authentication and which type of authentication node mailer would accept for fetching the share point document as an attachment.

Comment: Is it necessary to be a file link? You can authenticate the Sharepoint API at the server side, download it at the server side itself and send the file as attachment?